Software to fill-in images of forms as if they were digital forms
I prefer fill in forms digitally. Sometimes I only have an image of a form (like a scan, a picture, or a form-less PDF). I fill them using image editor programs, like Gimp or Inkscape. However the process is tedious.
Is there any piece of software that detects the fields in a form, chooses the right position, dimension and rotation for the text, and simply lets me click and type?
